# Best way to delete all specific type of NSManagedObjects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I have an entity called "Orders". What the best way to delete all of the orders? I know that I can query them and delete them one by one and then call save on the context, but is there a better, maybe more efficient proper way of doing this?

THnaks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, that's how you do it. Despite it usually using a database as a back-end data store, CoreData itself is not a database, it's a relational object graph manager. As such, there's no way to delete objects without actually fetching them and telling the context to delete them.